# how to install multiple phpmyadmin in ubuntu?

Tags: php-7.4, php-8.1

I'm using php7.4 in my ubuntu system, now I have to install **php8.1** along with the **php7.4**

php8.1 was installed successfully, but how can I install **PHPMyAdmin** for php8.1?

Or don't I need two **PHPMyAdmin** for the different PHP versions?

please advise me on this.

Thank you in advanced.

**i have update as per below answer it is right?**

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/newinstance.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName newinstance.example.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin/newinstance

    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/newinstance>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Install the phpMyAdmin package using the apt command. This will install the latest version of phpMyAdmin on your system.

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

2- Create a new directory for the additional phpMyAdmin instance. This directory will be used to store the configuration files and other assets for the new instance.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/newinstance
```

3- Copy the default phpMyAdmin configuration files from the /etc/phpmyadmin directory to the new directory you just created.

```
sudo cp -R /etc/phpmyadmin/* /usr/share/phpmyadmin/newinstance/
```

4- Edit the new configuration files in the /usr/share/phpmyadmin/newinstance directory and update the settings as needed. You can use the default configuration files as a starting point and make changes as required.

5- Create a new Apache virtual host configuration file for the new phpMyAdmin instance. This will allow you to access the new instance using a different URL.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/newinstance.conf
```

6- Add the following content to the new configuration file, replacing the placeholder values with your own values:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName newinstance.example.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin/newinstance

    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/newinstance>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

7- Enable the new virtual host configuration file and restart Apache to apply the changes.

```
sudo a2ensite newinstance.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

After completing these steps, you should be able to access the new instance of phpMyAdmin using the URL you specified in the virtual host configuration file. You can repeat these steps to create additional instances of phpMyAdmin on your system, each with its own configuration and URL.

Comment: in step 4 which file i need to configure again? i have updated my question and add newinstance.conf

Comment: and how to open PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "open"? start the phpmyadmin service? or to manage via web browser?